# Problems with parsing to pandas datatime

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I have some csv files that I need to analyse. There is a time date field in the csvs. The following is the format of the original column ;

```
2017/02/17-12:56
2017/02/17-12:58
2017/02/17-1:00
2017/02/17-1:02
2017/02/17-1:04
2017/02/17-1:06
```

As you can see its a 12 hour clock. I'm not sure if the '-' is causing me problems when parsing, so I've tired to strip that out however for some reason it wont strip it, here is what I've tired:

```
df['TimeDate'] = df['TimeDate'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip('-')) # doesnt strip

df['TimeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeDate'], format ='%Y/%m/%d-%I:%M') 
#error: time data 'TimeDate' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d-%I:%M' 

df.TimeDate = pd.to_datetime(df.TimeDate.str.strip('-'), format='%Y/%m/%d-%I:%M')
#error: time data 'TimeDate' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d-%I:%M'

df['TimeDate'] = df['TimeDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
#error: Error parsing datetime string "2017/03/14-11:32" at position 4
```

I'm not sure what else to do. Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can you check the data type in the csv?

Comment: @Data_Kid it just seems to be General

Comment: Please edit your question with raw data, code to re-create your df, any errors and your pandas, python and numpy version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use lambda

```
import pandas
l = """2017/02/17-12:56
2017/02/17-12:58
2017/02/17-1:00
2017/02/17-1:02
2017/02/17-1:04
2017/02/17-1:06"""



p = pandas.DataFrame(l.split('\n'))

p = p.apply(lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x))

>>p[0]
0   2017-02-17 12:56:00
1   2017-02-17 12:58:00
2   2017-02-17 01:00:00
3   2017-02-17 01:02:00
4   2017-02-17 01:04:00
5   2017-02-17 01:06:00
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Edit -- String format not working so try this

```
import pandas

l = """2017/02/17-12:56
2017/02/17-12:58
2017/02/17-1:00
2017/02/17-1:02
2017/02/17-1:04
2017/02/17-1:06"""
p = pandas.Series(l.split('\n'))
df = p.to_frame('DateTime')

df['Date'] = df['DateTime'].str.split('-').str.get(0)
df['time'] = df['DateTime'].str.split('-').str.get(1)
df['TimeDate'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['time'])

df
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i get the following error:
'Unknown string format', 'occurred at index TimeDate'

Comment: Which version of pandas do you have?

Comment: I have version 0.18.1

Comment: The dtype is of object if that makes a difference, does it need to be of type string ?

Comment: Not at all see if the new code works by splitting the string.

Comment: Also if your TimeDate is an index, make it a column first by df.reset_index()

Comment: great stuff thats worked, so splitting it and then recreating the series was required

Thanks alot